# Java Server not receiving all data that's being sent by python client

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I am writing a Server Client application using TCP/IP. The issue is that my python client has a loop that runs 400 times sending 400 individual data. But only 23 datas are being received on the server side.

Here's the server java code which is basically in infinite loop reading as much as sent by client

```
  BufferedReader br = null;
  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  str = br.readLine();
```

Here's the python client code that sends data

```
 for x in range (0, hmany):
        test =  "INSERT \t" + rstring(4) + " " + rstring(4) + " " + rdate() + "\n"
        client_socket.send(test)
```

rstring() and rdate() are just bunch of methods returning strings

Comment: If you add a short sleep (maybe `time.sleep(0.1)`) to the sending loop is there a change?

Comment: No it made no difference.. It did take little while for complete execution of 400 data, but total data being received is still less

Comment: Try using flush